# How to get largest number in an array without using any extra variable or built in function

Tags: java

How to get largest number in an array without using any extra variable or built in function.

```
Sample Input: int arr[] = {4,5,87,-9,1,0,34,5,,8};
Sample O/p: 87
```

Comment: Writing some code is a good start. Besides, I am quite sure that this is not possible. You cannot iterate through the array without any "extra variables". http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: "*without using any extra variable or built in function.*"  May I just ask.. *why*?

Comment: @Turing85 im not going to do it because (a) I think they've misunderstood what they need to do and (b) you're right about needing an attempt but I think you could possibly do it by hard coding the comparison of the first 3 items then using them as your variables to use to iterate over and hold the maximum so far and hold the best of the first 3 (determined by hardcoded comparisons)

Comment: @RichardTingle depends on how you define "extra variable". `for (int i = ...)` and `for (int i : ...) ` have an extra variable (the `i` in both cases). You could, of course, hard-code a solution for all `2^31` indices... but I doubt that this is what is supposed to be done.

Comment: @Turing85 you need a while loop and any time you want to refer to `i` you refer to `arr[0]` and any time you want to refer to `maxSoFar` you refer to `arr[1]` after clearing those out in the short hard coded bit at the beginning (that puts it's result in `arr[2]`)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8 or above you can do something like:

```
int[] arr = { 4, 5, 87, -9, 1, 0, 34, 5, 0, 8 };
int maxNum = java.util.Arrays.stream(arr).max().getAsInt();
```

Take a look at [java.util.stream.IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) interface documentation for more features.

Answer (score 0):

Check with array first element and compare with rest of all the elements of array.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = {4,5,87,-9,1,0,34,5,8};
   
    for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
       if(arr[0]<arr[i]){
         arr[0]=arr[i];
       }
    }
    System.out.println("largest element : "+arr[0]);
 }
```